# chosen plugin not working with dynamically created rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I must say that I am beginner in JQuery but I usually try to figure out and solve problems by myself. However now I have a problem and i am stuck 
I have a table with dynamically added rows and select box for each for the purpose of single delete or multiple delete, everything works fine except than when rows are added chosen is applied but select boxes aren't functioning no matter what i do nothing works.

HTML

```
<table id="dataTable">
<tr>
  <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" value="selectAll"/></th>
  <th>Field-1</th>
  <th>Field-2</th>
  <th>Field-3</th>
  <th>Field-4</th>
  <th>Field-5</th>
</tr>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  class="check"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="input-1[]" class="chosen_select_L">
                <option></option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input name="input-2[]" type="text" class="chosen_text"></td>
        <td><input name="input-3[]" type="text" class="chosen_text"></td>
        <td><input name="input-4[]" type="text" class="chosen_text"></td>
        <td>
            <select name="input-5[]" class="chosen_select_M">
                <option></option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add Field" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
<input type="button" value="Remove Field" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  />
```

JS

```
$(".chosen_select_L").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
  });
$(".chosen_select_M").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectall').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) { 
            $('.check').each(function() { 
                this.checked = true; 
            });
        }else{
            $('.check').each(function() { 
                this.checked = false; 
            });        
        }
    });
});

function addRow(dataTable) {
    var table = document.getElementById(dataTable);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 11){
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum fields is 10.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(dataTable) {
    var table = document.getElementById(dataTable);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=2; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
                alert("Cannot Remove all fields.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried giving different ids or class names, visually everything looks fine but not a single select box is actually working except in the first row which wasn't dynamically created.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwgyt42u/) for you guys to check out.
Any help would much appreciated. THANKS

Comment: You need to instantiate the `chosen()` method in the `addRow()` function as well as on load.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan for your input on the subject, i tried your advice and i got to say it is remarkable i just don't really know how to implement it in my code as i ended up with a working dynamically added select box but unfortunately i got duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the corrected [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwgyt42u/1/). You need destroy chosen using

`$(".chosen_select_L").chosen('destroy');`

before getting the innerHTML and then re-initialize it after appending the contents.

Comment: Thank you @jacky , you've solved a problem that was making me crazy for almost 3 days. Very much appreciated

Comment: Do you need to destroy chosen globally? On the entire page? And only then re-initiate it?